# merge two rows if first column is same in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following data

```
11111 | aff | baucj | blah | blah
13331 | azvaff | bcacj | blah | blah
11111 | aasfff | aascj | blah | blah
13331 | aafzvff | baucj | blah | blah
12221 | arthrf | bacsfucj | blah | blah
12221 | ddhrhsd | hdafasfacj | blah | blah
```

I want these to be merged like

```
11111 | aff | baucj | blah | blah | 11111 | aasfff | aascj | blah | blah
13331 | azvaff | bcacj | blah | blah | 13331 | aafzvff | baucj | blah | blah
12221 | arthrf | bacsfucj | blah | blah | 12221 | ddhrhsd | hdafasfacj | blah | blah
```

Comment: `@user2705779` what you tried so far...?

Comment: Does the order of the merged lines matter? Can a first column value occur more than two times?

Comment: yes it can and can't. It's a big file and checking would take me a while.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
find what: ^(\S+)(.+?)\n((?:(?!\1).*)?)(\1 .+?)\n
replace by: $1$2 | $4\n$3
```

Check "regular expression" and "dot match newline" (I'm not sure about these labels, I haven't english version of NP++)

Comment: @user2705779: Try to change all the `\n` with `\r\n`

Comment: this only replaces 2 lines one by one, i mean i have to click replace all two times.

Comment: this only replaces 2 lines one by one, i mean i have to click replace all two times.